# htaccess redirect based on URL stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Here is what I want to do:

- User comes to my site from `www.mysite.com/advert1` (folder advert1 doesn't exist)
- `.htaccess` then removes `www.mysite.com/` leaving just `advert1`
- Store `advert1` as a string in a cookie
- Look for `advert1` in a database then redirect the user to the URL specified in the database e.g `mysite.com/news`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the rule such where all requests are directed to a external script.
Then the server script may look up the database, set cookies and redirect. The .htaccess can not do this by itself unless you write a extension for apache which is likely to be beyond the scope the application you need right now.

For now just redirect all requests to a script by

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-])$ /advert.php?id=$1 [L]
```

you can use `$ad_string = $_GET["id"];` to get the ad string in the $ad_string variable. Then you can make a connection to the database using `mysql_connect()` and then run a sql query like `"SELECT * FROM advert_table WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($ad_string) . "'"` This should sort out your url for the query. then use a `meta redirect` or a `javascript redirect` or even a `header 301 redirect.`

Comment: Great thank you very much, but how do I pass over that "adver1" string to a php script? and how do I pass the link from the database to the browser?